# Syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead. MYSQL DOCKER

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

I am trying to get rid of this warning but I can't figure out where it is coming from. Has anyone been able to fix the warning?

I never used skip-host in my application but I am still getting the warning. I also try tried to use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 in sql script but it did not work.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-30.html#mysqld-8-0-30-deprecation-removal.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I tried to set the global host cache size to 0 but I still got the warning.